# Number display as # in generated Excel file

Tags: excel, jasper-reports

I have an *Excel* file generated by *JasperReports*. What you can see here is the *Excel*'s column will be display ### if the number is too long. I don't want to resize the width of column, i just want to display the number without seen as ### and stretch the height. I have tried set the column to `Stretch with overflow` and `Stretch type` = `Relative to band height`

This is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i want the column show the number, not ###. the width is fixed and its in number format. i expect the column's height can be stretch and show the full number.

Comment: Changing the hight won't help. Maybe change format to Scientific?

Comment: i changed to Text format and its worked, but i cant control the pattern such as how many decimal point should be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the appropriate Jasper Reports excel property on your report element, or on the whole report iself.  Documentation: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsfeatures/

Specifically

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.column.width.ratio
```

If these properties are not available in your JasperReports version, you may have to simply fiddle around with the sizing to get something decent.

Comment: this is not the answer that i want, btw thanks for the some knowledge.